# How to subtract a second (or more) from a Countdown Timer in Android?

Tags: java, android, button, timer

I am new to countdown timer so I have no idea about this issue. I tried many things but I didn't get what I expected.
This is my code for the timer. It is a class within a class as usual.

```
// TIMER
    public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {

        public Timer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            //getNgo(true, score, tries, secLeft);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            //secLeft = millisUntilFinished;

            int sec = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            sec = sec % 60;
            int min = sec / 60;
            tvTime.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            if (sec <= 10) {

                animScale(tvTime);

                tvTime.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                tvTime.setText("" + min + ":" + sec);

                if (sec < 10) {
                    tvTime.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    tvTime.setText("" + min + ":0" + sec);
                }

            } else {
                tvTime.setText("" + min + ":" + sec);
            }
        }

    }
```

So, I just wanted to know how to deduct 3 seconds (that will be 3000 ms) when I push the button and the timer that is displayed by the textview will go on ticking but the time has already been deducted. And where do I put the code. Thanks!

Comment: I've editted to remove "with push of button" since I'm inferring from your question you understand how to set up the handler, just not how to manage the timer.

Answer (score 0):

When I've had to do this with tasks scheduled to take place in a fixed time, I've:

1. Cancelled the original task.
2. Submitted a new one with the new time period.

I suspect that this is a more standard pattern than your use of `Timer` anyway.

e.g.:

```
private final Runnable task = new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { /* ... */ } };

private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor();

private final long initialSeconds = 3;

public void submitTask() {
    stpe.schedule(task, initialSeconds, TimeUnit.Seconds());
}

public void subtractSeconds(long sec) {
    if(stpe.remove(task)) {
        stpe.schedule(task, Math.Max(initialSeconds - sec, 0), TimeUnit.Seconds);
    }
}
```

You will need to figure out:

- how to ensure task is only initially-submitted once and keep track of fixed variable
- whether you need one fixed `final` task or that task to be changed
- concurrency/multithreading issues if the task can be submitted more than once

Comment: i can say, ur answer is already advance. i can't understand some of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a simple countdown using one of the stackoverflow posts

```
// gets current time  
long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();  
/* timer holds the values of the current second the timer should display  
 * requiredTime is the start value that the countdown should start from  
 * startTime is the time when the application starts  
*/  
timer = requiredTime - (timeNow - startTime) / 1000;  
if (timer >= 0)   
    timer.setText(String.valueOf(timer));
```

To subtract the timer, subtract requiredTime and it will work. Because you've changed the reference value.

```
// Override onClickListener and add the line
// to deduct 3 seconds
requiredTime -= 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't. You have to write your own `CountDownTimer`. Copy original code and add method

```
public synchronized void addTime(long millis) {
    mStopTimeInFuture += millis;
}
```

Then set `onClickListener` to the button

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        timer.addTime(-2000);       
    }
});
```

[Here](http://wklej.org/id/964941/) is full sample code

Comment: That method does not need to be synchronized provided `mStopTimeInFuture` is declared `volatile`.

Comment: Will this work if there are 2 seconds left and you subtract 3?  I suspect not so I'm downvoting until this is addressed (and will revoke DV if I am wrong and it is explained why.)

Comment: that's one thing i wanna know too. :/

Comment: If int sec was a global/instance variabel, can't you just check if there is more than 3 seconds left using an if statement?

Comment: @RaymondP not without a race condition.

Comment: @djechlin, yes it will work if 2 seconds left and you subtract 3.

Comment: @abc667 can you explain why?

Comment: When you subtract 3 seconds in `handleMessage()` variable `millisLeft` will be smaller than 0 and `onFinish()` will be called...

Comment: @djechlin, did you check that? You can simply copy my sample code and add button and textview to layout.